# Change footer text color. Background Change?

Tags: text, colors, background, footer

I am having trouble changing the text color of my footer.  I have it arranged like I want, but it's not changing color like I want it to.  I've tried many ways to change it, and finally just decided to ask someone.  Also if someone could tell me how to add a background similar to the page of my website.  I would be much appreciative.  But I mainly need to change the text color.  Here is a link to the current theme of the website I am changing.
http://www.bbcardmore.com/
The new theme has a gray background which makes the text of the footer barely read-able.  So please help me.  :)

Edit: I have since fixed the issue with my text by doing something simple.  I now have my text looking as I want.  But if anyone could help me with creating a background for my footer.  I'd be grateful.
Scroll down to see the updated HTML.

CSS

```
    /* =Footer
    -------------------------------------------------------------- */
    .left{
    text-align:left;float:left;margin-left:17px;
    color:#191e26;
    }
    .right{
    float:right;text-align:right;
    color:#191e26;
    }
    .centered{
    float:left;margin-left:160px;text-align:center;
    color:#191e26;
    }
```

Old HTML

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <head>
    </style>
    <head>
<div id="footer">
 <div class="left">
 <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><font size="5" color="red">About Us</font><br /></p></h3>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC History" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-history-3/">BBC History</a>                 <br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Statement Of Faith" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/statement-of- faith/">BBC Statement Of Faith</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Ministries" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-ministries/">BBC Ministries</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Pastor" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/our-pastor/">BBC Pastor</a><br />  </p>
     <p style="padding-bottom: 0pt; " class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Map"  href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">BBC Map</a></p>
        </div>  

 <div class="centered">
 <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font size="5" color="red">Service Times</font><br /></p></h3>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday School~ 10:00 AM</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Morning Service~ 11:00 AM</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Sunday Evening Service~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Wednesday Evening Bible Study~ 7:00 PM</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"> Transportation and child-care available for all services.</a><br /></p>
            </div>

   <div class="right">
<h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="5" color="red">Contact Us:</font><br /></p></h3>
    <p class="paragraph_style_2"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font size="3" color="red">Physical Address:</font><br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">1515 Easley Drive<br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/">Ardmore, OK 73401<br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="" href="mailto:bbcardmore@aol.com"><font size="3" color="red">Email:</font></span> bbcardmore@aol.com<br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="3" color="red">Phone:</font></span> (580) 223-6629<br /></p>
        </div>
       <div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

​
     New HTML

```
    <body>
    <head>
    </style>
    <head>
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="left">
    <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><font size="5" color="#b42a1e">About Us</font><br /></p></h3>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC History" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-history-3/"><font color="#191e26">BBC History</font></a>                 <br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Statement Of Faith" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/statement-of- faith/"><font color="#191e26">BBC Statement Of Faith</a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Ministries" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/bbc-ministries/"><font color="#191e26">BBC Ministries</font></a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Pastor" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/our-pastor/"><font color="#191e26">BBC Pastor</font></a><br />  </p>
     <p style="padding-bottom: 0pt; " class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="BBC Map"  href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font color="#191e26">BBC Map</font></a></p>
        </div>  

 <div class="centered">
 <h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font size="5" color="#b42a1e">Service Times</font><br /></p></h3>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font color="#191e26"> Sunday School~ 10:00 AM</font></a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font color="#191e26"> Sunday Morning Service~ 11:00 AM</font></a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font color="#191e26"> Sunday Evening Service~ 7:00 PM</font></a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font color="#191e26"> Wednesday Evening Bible Study~ 7:00 PM</font></a><br /></p>
     <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Service Times" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/service-times/"><font color="#191e26"> Transportation and child-care available for all services.</font></a><br /></p>
            </div>

   <div class="right">
<h3><p style="padding-top: 10pt; " class="paragraph_style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="5" color="#b42a1e">Contact Us:</font><br /></p></h3>
    <p class="paragraph_style_2"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font size="3" color="#b42a1e">Physical Address:</font><br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font color="#191e26">1515 Easley Drive</font><br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_1"><a title="Map" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/map/"><font color="#191e26">Ardmore, OK 73401</font><br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="" href="mailto:bbcardmore@aol.com"><font size="3" color="#b42a1e">Email:</font></span><font color="#191e26"> bbcardmore@aol.com</font><br /></p>
    <p class="paragraph_style_3"><span class="style"><a title="Contact Us" href="http://www.bbcardmore.com/contact-us/"><font size="3" color="#b42a1e">Phone:</font></span><font color="#191e26"> (580) 223-6629</font><br /></p>
        </div>
       <div>
      </body>
     </html>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Do you want change the **red** color ?

```
<font size="5" color="red">About Us</font>
```

Delete **color="red"**

Comment: I want to keep the red actually.  It's the rest of the text I am meaning to change.

Comment: I did that, no effect.  And i'm meaning to change the gray text to a color such as black.

Comment: I figured out what I needed to do.  I was just putting the "font color="black">/font>" in the wrong place.  I have figured out what I need to do.  However; if someone can help me with getting a background on my footer without messing with the location of the text; I would be grateful.

Comment: #footer {background: gray;overflow: hidden;}